# Convergence in distribution using strong law of large numbers

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(X_n)_n$ be an i.i.d sequence of random variables defined on the same probability space and denote $S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k.$

Assume that $\mathbb{E}(X_1)\ne0$ and  given $\alpha>0$ that $$\sqrt{n}(X_n-\alpha\mathbb{1}_{\{S_n\ne 0\}})\overset{d}{\to} \frac{X_1}{\mathbb{E}(X_1)}.$$

I would like to deduce that $\sqrt{n}(X_n-\alpha)$ converge in distribution. My idea is to use the strong long of large numbers that $\mathbb{1}_{\{S_n\ne 0\}}\overset{\text{a.e.}}\to 1$ but not sure how can I conclude.

Comment: Maybe there is a typo

Comment: @anonymus where ?

Comment: The indicator function is on the whole term : ?

Comment: @anonymus ah perhaps, the result is true if the indicator is on the whole term ?

Comment: I am saying that I think the indicator is on the whole term, and then you can use Slutsky lemma if you know that $1_{\{S_n \neq 0\}}\to 1$ a.s.

Comment: Please do not just delete question that have an answer. If there is a particular reason why you want to do this, please at least explain it.

Comment: @quid oops, it was not intentional. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write
$$\sqrt{n}(X_n-\alpha)=\sqrt{n}(X_n-\alpha \mathbb{1}_{\{S_n\ne 0\}})+\sqrt{n}\alpha(\mathbb{1}_{\{S_n\ne 0\}}-1).$$
Since $\mathbb{1}_{\{S_n\ne 0\}}$ can take values $0\vee 1$ only, convergence $\mathbb{1}_{\{S_n\ne 0\}}\overset{\text{a.e.}}\to 1$ means that for every elementary event $\omega\in A$, where $\mathbb P(A)=1$, there exists $N=N(\omega)$ s.t. for all $n\geq N$
$$
\mathbb{1}_{\{S_n\ne 0\}}(\omega):=\mathbb{1}_{\{S_n(\omega)\ne 0\}} = 1.
$$
So, for every $\omega\in A$ and for each $n\geq N$ the additional term vanishes: 
$$\sqrt{n}\alpha(\mathbb{1}_{\{S_n\ne 0\}}-1)(\omega)=0.$$
We proved that 
$$
\sqrt{n}\alpha(\mathbb{1}_{\{S_n\ne 0\}}-1)\overset{\text{a.e.}}\to 0.
$$
Next use Slutsky theorem as proposed by [anonymus](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/277855/anonymus).